# Desktop Browser Simulators for Mobile

Tags: javascript

I want to know if you can do the following:
When viewing a page from mobile that the agent detects that it is not mobile but believes that it is "desktop", is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Chrome for Android has this option natively.

Comment: No, I want this behavior to have all users who visit the page from a mobile.

Comment: ... so just don't make the page do anything different for mobile vs desktop users. That's the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can go the the settings from chrome and android and click view as desktop which will make you view the website as if you are viewing it from your computer

Comment: No, I want this behavior to have all users who visit the page from a mobile.